# How to print ipp printer setup

Tags: php, printing, ip, localhost

So I'm trying to print a file generated by PHP in my localhost through PHP code. I was told to check http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/ and I found this code that they state as the easiest setup in their documentation.

```
<?php

    require_once(PrintIPP.php);

    $ipp = new PrintIPP();
    $ipp->setHost("localhost");
    $ipp->setPrinterURI("/printers/epson");
    $ipp->setData("./testfiles/test-utf8.txt"); // Path to file.
    $ipp->printJob();

?>
```

As a beginner, I made this basic logic by looking at the code above. First of all, I generate the .txt file through PHP.

Secondly, I create this new instance of the class and so on the objects do the following: find the host (which is localhost in my case, so no need to edit), **find the printer**, find the text file to be printed (already generated), and do the print job. Yes I know it seems pretty straightforward, but it seems I can't find the printer URI.

How to do that as I am totally unfamiliar to this... I guess the printer must have some kind of IP in the localhost (not sure). If so How can I find it?

Answer (score 4):

**Hi!**

I'm the PHP::PRINT::IPP author

You'd better to sent to the mailing list (this is a really asynchronous response)

:)

**phpprintipp@nongnu.org**

- In first I strongly recommends to check the cvs repository:

  cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.savannah.nongnu.org:/sources/phpprintipp co phpprintipp

(you needs cvs program)

- automagically find printers works *only with CUPS server*, and I didn't check for 3 years :)

If you print directly to a network printer (without CUPS), or use another IPP server than CUPS:

- check  your printer/server manual for handling of documents formats you whish to use (most probably you'll get only text/plain and PostScript, and as an option for last even on high quality printers, the mime type **"application/octet-stream"**  designates **either** your *printer's language* (PCL, ...) **-- which is not the standard regarding rfc2911 --** or *document format auto-detection* **which is the standard**). You can request for **document-format-supported** or the whole printer's characteristics with PHP::PRINT::IPP while connected to server (see documentation on **main site** (URI given at that post end)
- points your **web browser** to **IP/fqdn** of *your printer/or print server* **port 631**

  eg:

  ```
  http:// xxx . xxx . xxx . xxx : 631
  ```

(IPv6 addresses are OK too in php::print::ipp, but I never try with a web browser (most probably use brackets [::1]:631))

- (you are in web browser server-IP:631) check for the "printers" paths eg: "/epson/"
  => paths are done on "CUPS" basis in BasicIpp:

  ```
  public $paths = array(
    "root" => "/",
    "admin" => "/admin/",
    "printers" => "/printers/",
    "jobs" => "/jobs/"
  );
  ```

  => so

  ```
  $ipp->paths = array(
    "root" => "/blah/",
    "admin" => "/bluh/",
    "printers" => "/blih/",
    "jobs" => "/bloh/"
  );
  ```

  => most probably "/blah/" "/blah/" "/blah/" "/blah/" for the four paths :)

  => **can also be "/" for the 4**

  ("jobs" designates the jobs (printings) control/check path, and "root", well, if you don't know that then you most probably uses MS-Windows which *MS-Windows IPP embedded server will not be usable with that library* -- excepting maybe for text/plain)

*note: It would be cool if s.o. could install the "PostScript driver" on a MS-Windows server then checks for handling of at least PostScript format with PHP::PRINT::IPP or other IPP clients*

- (you are in web browser server-IP:631) check for your "printer-uri" as done in the print server setup.

  => then :

  ```
  $ipp->setPrinterURI($uri)
  ```

**WARNING** 
  => this has nothing to do with

```
setUnix($socket = '/var/run/cups/cups.sock')
```

nor

```
setHost($host = 'localhost') + setPort($port = '631')
```

These 3 last functions gives *connectivity to print server*

- => another way to find relevant informations is to print "IPP server/printer setup page" in the printer's menu you'll find on (any ?) network printer hardware. *Beware to choose the page which gives you "IPP setup"*, as most persons are not aware of and sent me "general information" or "general network setup".

[main site](http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/) (links to doc, install, whatever... They are afraid of spam here :)

[project / cvs / news](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/phpprintipp)

### Regards,

TSFH

phpprintipp@nongnu.org